# How can I find out what kind of relationship between a parent bone and the child, using python?

Tags: python, bones, parent

How do I know the type of parent that has a bone, connected or offset? using Python in blender 2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit mode, relations panel**
[image]

As is displayed in the relations panel of a bone in edit mode, can look at the properties in the python console.

Simple armatrure, active and in edit mode. List each edit bones `EditBone.parent` and `EditBone.use_connect` properties.

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Armature']

>>> bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
{'FINISHED'}

>>> for b in C.object.data.edit_bones:
...     b.name, b.parent, b.use_connect
...     
('Bone.002', None, False)
('Bone', bpy.data.armatures['Armature']...EditBone, False)
('Bone.001', bpy.data.armatures['Armature']...EditBone, True)
```

**Pose / Object Mode**

or similarly in Object or pose mode by looking at the armature objects  pose bones collection.

```
>>> for pb in C.object.pose.bones:
...     pb.name, getattr(pb.parent, "name", None), pb.bone.use_connect
...     
('Bone', 'Bone.002', False)
('Bone.002', None, False)
('Bone.001', 'Bone', True)

>>>
```